# loop over a list of HDF5 files

Tags: python-2.7, hdf5

I would like to loop over a list of .HDF5 data files, and make some operations after that. So in order to make not each operation on each file individually I would like to loop over it.
I did the following...

```
import os
import h5py

# Read in 2A.GPM.DPR
os.chdir('/home/unix/Desktop/source')
file_name = ['2A.GPM.DPR.V6-20160118.20150620-S060925-E074157.007431.V04A.HDF5',
             '2A.GPM.DPR.V6-20160118.20150801-S100900-E114133.008087.V04A.HDF5']
for n in file_name:
    print n
    #
    f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
    ##
```

After that I get the following error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-e6813194d502> in <module>()
      6     print n
      7     #
----> 8     f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')

/home/unix/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, **kwds)
    265                     # encoding, just pass it on as-is.  Note Unicode
    266                     # objects can always be encoded.
--> 267                     name = name.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    268                 except (UnicodeError, LookupError):
    269                     pass

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

So do you know what this error could be? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not opening the files, but instead you are feeding a list to the `.File` method. You should change your code to the following:

```
import os
import h5py

# Read in 2A.GPM.DPR
os.chdir('/home/unix/Desktop/source')
file_names = ['2A.GPM.DPR.V6-20160118.20150620-S060925-E074157.007431.V04A.HDF5',
             '2A.GPM.DPR.V6-20160118.20150801-S100900-E114133.008087.V04A.HDF5']
for file_name in file_names:
    print file_name
    #
    f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
    ##
```

You're looping through your list of file names and providing ***one file name*** at a time.

I hope this helps.